# Objective-C protocol not recognized in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, interop, protocols

I am working in an app written in Objective-C and we would like to begin integrating some Swift into it.

I have written a simple view controller class in Swift and to work in the app it must conform to a protocol that was written in Objective-C. In my Swift class I have the following declaration:

```
@objc class SwfViewController: UIViewController, theProtocolName {
    //some code
}
```

In my bridging header file I have the class name of the protocol referenced.

```
#import "theProtocolName.h"
```

I have implemented all of the required methods listed in the protocol, yet still I get an error saying

> SwfViewController does not conform to protocol 'theProtocolName'

I'm fairly new to Swift and could have easily left out something. Any suggestions of what to check? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add the code of the protocol and the implementation of SwfViewController? Likely, you have declared the methods in SwfViewController wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take into account that Swift signature for methods is slightly different from objective-c. For example:

A protocol like this:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

  - (void)didFinish:(MyClass *)class withError:(id)errorMessage;

@end
```

A class that conforms to this protocol in Swift should be:

```
@objc class SwfViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
  func didFinish(whatEveryouWant1: UIViewController!, withError whatEverYouWant2: AnyObject!){

  }
}
```

Please note id becomes AnyObject and Obj-C references are translated with ! as implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error means that your class is missing required methods which is the part of the point of the protocol. The class seems to realize that it need to follow the protocol you've told it about, but now need to define the required pieces.

You should be able to expand the error message by clicking on it to find out which pieces are missing.

Comment: "You should be able to expand the error message by clicking on it to find out which pieces are missing." <-- I don't think you can do this in Swift.